# Forming the union of two sets seems to give wrong and inconsistent answers

Tags: c++, stdset, set-union

The following code is my attempt to form the union of the two element set {2,3} with the empty set {}. I expect that the resulting container (in this case, a list) should have size 2.

However, when I run the code, I get that the size of the union is 0 or 3, depending on which of the two indicated locations for the declaration of the variable `united`. Neither of these results is what I expected and they clearly can't both be correct.

What am I missing here?

```
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>  
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //list<int> united; // resulting output is 3

    int d1[] = {2,3};
    set<int> dom1(d1, d1+2);
    set<int> dom2;

    list<int> united; // resulting output is 0

    set_union(dom1.begin(), dom1.end(), dom2.begin(), dom2.end(), united.begin());

    cout << united.size();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the documentation of [`std::set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) you'll find that the fifth iterator must meet the requirements of [OutputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator).

Then, if you take a look at the documentation of [`std::list::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/begin), you'll find that it returns a [`std::list::iterator` (or `std::list::const_iterator`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list#Iterators), which is only a [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) which is a subtype of [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator).

Technically, a non const InputIterator is also an OutputIterator but that behaves in a way that does not work for your program. It iterates the nodes of `united` and copy-assigns the source elements over the ones already existing. But since `united` is empty in your case, the iterator goes out of bounds, resulting in undefined behaviour.

An easy way to get an OutputIterator that inserts new elements, is to use the [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Answer (score 2):

In general, whenever you get "wrong and inconsistent answers", you have undefined behaviour, or your program is otherwise ill-formed without having been diagnosed. Look for out-of-range bugs.

**Here, your output iterator refers to a range that does not exist.**

You should replace `united.begin()` with `std::back_inserter(united)`, so that elements are created as needed.

This is per the example in [the cppreference.com `std::set_union` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union).
*Read the documentation!*